# kde5 using too much cpu

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I am using Archlinux with KDE5, and the plasma shell did not work well since a recent update.

It's using too much cpu and the cpu cores are getting very hot. Both cores go up to 85 degrees centigrade. Under Gnome the temperature was 60

By the way, such issue does not happen under plasma media center environment.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The bug is supposed to be fixed at this point in time 01/13/2017, but it is definitely still broken at least in Kubuntu 16.04

```
$ killall plasmashell; kstart plasmashell; exit
```

Running the above line is only a temporary solution, but it avoides a lot of reboots.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that's still being worked out: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=348385

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was connected with background image slideshow. When I switch to solid background plasmashell behaves normally.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381000

Answer (score -1):

KDE is an energy hog. Maybe try a lighter DE such as Kfce? or you could use just a simple window manager. What type of internals does your computer have?